# convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

proof attempt:

Let $X_n \to C$ in distribution where $C$ is a constant.

Now consider $P(|X_n-C|>\epsilon)$.

We know that $lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n <x)=1$ if $x>C$ and $0$ elsewhere.

So $P(X_n<x)>1-\epsilon$ for large enough $n$ and $x\geq C$.

So $P(X_n<x)<\epsilon$ for large enough $n$ and $x<C$.

Then what?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751259/convergence-in-distribution-implies-cv-in-probability-only-when-the-limit-is-con/2751273#2751273